# Using JMeter through a ssh tunnel and a proxy

Tags: proxy, jmeter, ssh-tunnel

I have a web application which I need to access with JMeter through a putty tunnel and a proxy.

Client -> www.example.com -> dynamic ssh tunnel on port:9999 -> proxy -> web application on port 80/8080.

For chrome I use Foxy Proxy to tunnel traffic through `localhost` on port `9999` which works, but I want a JMeter to work as well.

I can edit my host file to redirect `www.example.com` through `localhost`, but how do I tunnel the request through port `9999`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

1. Start your ssh tunnel on port 9999
2. Add HTTP Request Defaults under your thread group
3. State SSH tunnel in Proxy Server of HTTP Request Defaults as per below:

[image]

I hope this is working for you.

Comment: Cool. Please set my answer as the correct solution. So other people can notice easily about the correct solution :-)